# Vista/7 CoreAudio pascal files for Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-vista, core-audio

I've been looking all around for the CoreAudio pascal files and I can't find them. I searched the Rad Studio XE2 source directory to no avail.

On Google I found some partial files but none I found was the whole package or seem to include IAudioSessionManager2.

Are there any definitions that include new features in Win 7 or will I have to do my own conversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[They are](http://code.google.com/p/mfpack-media-foundation/source/browse/trunk/MFPACK/CoreAudio/Docs/Core+Audio+headers.txt?r=128) at the [MFPack on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/mfpack-media-foundation/)

Answer (score 1):

MfPack is moved to SourceForge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfpack).
Google gave up their hosting service for sourcecode.